# Natural gas fire pit

Tags: pipe, gas, pressure

My plumber piped a 1" gas line from my home to our fire pit. Its a 300k btu burner. The kit cam with a gas valve, 2 tee's some fittings and 2 gas lines. The plumber only used one line from the gas valve to the burner. The manufacturer advised that 2 are needed to increase the pressure to the burner. The plumber states that we wont get any more gas when the 2 lines are installed and are not needed. Can adding the tee's and the extra line increase pressure? Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: Will not increase pressure, but increase flow rate, if they are smaller.  What size are the two gas lines?

Comment: (2) 36” L x 3/4” Diameter Flex Lines. The manufacture states it will provide more pressure.

Answer (score 2):

**When gas is flowing** what the manufacturer says is certainly true.

Won't increase the pressure in the line (obviously), or when gas is not flowing but WILL **decrease** the **pressure loss** due to a single 3/4" flex .vs. 1" hard pipe. Spltting the flow into two 3/4 flex will definitely affect the delivered pressure (upwards) by decreasing the flow (and friction) in each of those flex pipes, relative to a single flex pipe.

There's also the *presumptive* code (and UL listing) issue (electrical code works this way, I presume gas would as well, but I don't have gas available so I don't have much to do with it) of **not following the manufacturer's instructions** for installation.

Due to basic pipe geometry, a 3/4" pipe has just over half (56%) the area of a 1" pipe. Due to flex geometry, flex has more friction (pressure drop) than hard pipe. Two 3/4" flex pipes can deliver just about all a 1" pipe can supply. One 3/4" flex pipe cannot.

Comment: Thank you for your help explaining this to me!